# strncpy from **char to *char[] not copying last element

Tags: c, arrays, strncpy

I'm trying to copy the individual elements of `argv` into a 2nd array. I'm using `strncpy` to do it.

Here's a stripped version that replicates the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    char *argvarray[argc];
    int arrlen;

    //int j;
    for(int j=0; j< argc; j++){
        arrlen = arrlen + strlen(argv[j]);
    }

    printf("size of argv: %d\n", arrlen); //see if size is right
    strncpy(*argvarray, *argv, arrlen);

    for(int j=0; j< argc; j++){
        printf("value of j: %d\n", j); //to see what's going on
        printf("%s\n", argv[j]); 
        printf("%s\n", argvarray[j]); //gets 1st element no problem
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I pass 1 arg to main it copies the first element of `argv` to `argvarray` but the second is not copied. If I pass more than 1 arg it segfaults on `strncpy()`.

Why is this happening? What's the best way to copy all elements of a char array (particularly char arrays declared in function definitions) to other char arrays without knowing the size before hand, as in the case of `argv`?

Comment: You never allocate memory to which the elements in `argvarray` could point to.

Comment: `arrlen` is not initialized.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the assistance, and your patience as I learn.

Comment: Study arrays and pointers in detail before moving on to string handling.

Comment: @Lundin That's exactly what I'm doing, studying arrays and pointers. I'm a 30 year programmer (of a different sort) and I suspect that's actually a detriment to me learning C. But, I learn best through practical use of individual concepts as opposed to volumes of discourse on theory and arbitrary example. Since I primarily work with strings and ints it's imperative that I understand how to apply arrays and pointers to strings and ints. Ergo, the request for assistance in learning how to apply them.

Answer (score 3):

```
arrlen = arrlen + strlen(argv[j]);
```

`arrlen` is used uninitialized (undefined behaviour).

And as pointed out By @PeterA.Schneider, you need room for each element of `argvarray`, use `malloc` before `strncpy` or `strdup`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate all the constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about arrays vs pointers.

If you declare an array `char tab[2][3]`, it'll be stored contiguously in memory:

```
[h][e][y][y][o][u] (a simple example).
```

But here, you have pointers, so `char (*tab)[2]` is an array of two pointers:

```
tab = [0x1234][0x5678]
0x1234 = "hey"
0x5678 = "you"
```

`strncpy` copies contiguous parts of memory. To copy `argv`, copy each pointer instead (call malloc + strcpy one for each `char*` is the easiest option)

(also see @AlterMann's answer, which is correct as well)

Comment: YES! Arrays are kicking my butt. Pointers aren't much better. If I weren't in need of a better understanding of C I'd probably rather spend time juggling knives. I'll get there eventually though (I hope)

Answer (score 1):

1. `arrlen` is not initialised. You increase its value then attempt to use it as a parameter to `strncpy`. The program behaviour will be undefined. Write `int arrlen = 0;` instead.
2. `argvarray` is an *array* of pointers to `char`. You don't allocate any memory for each element. `*argvarray` is equivalent to `argvarray[0]` which is a `char*` that doesn't point to anything. So, the behaviour of `strncpy` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that variable `arrlen` was not initialized

```
int arrlen;
```

and as result the value of the variable after execution the loop

```
for(int j=0; j< argc; j++){
    arrlen = arrlen + strlen(argv[j]);
}
```

will be indeterminate this call

```
strncpy(*argvarray, *argv, arrlen);
```

does not make sense and has undefined behaviour.

I think what you mean is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    char *argvarray[argc];

    for ( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        argvarray[i] = malloc( strlen( argv[i] ) + 1 ); 
        strcpy( argvarray[i], argv[i] );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        printf( "value of i: %d\n", i ); //to see what's going on
        printf( "%s\n", argv[i] ); 
        printf( "%s\n", argvarray[i] ); //gets 1st element no problem
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) free( argvarray[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million. I see how the other answers were basically the same as yours, but your example of usage really helped clarify it. Quality answer!!